# Android Kernel Additional Info

Tags: java, android, eclipse, kernel

I'm new to android programming and I tried to get all info of my kernel.

I'm using the OnePlus One CM1144S with franco.Kernel

My settings show me the follwoing info of my kernel:

**Kernel-Version:**

```
3.4.67-fanco.Kernel

root@franciscofranco #33

Mon Nov 17 20:12:2014 UTC 2014
```

**When I use:**

```
System.getProperty("os.version");
```

**I just get:**

```
3.4.67-fanco.Kernel
```

Now my question:
how to get the other info?
THANK YOU GUYS!!!